# node module - aes256 - crypto.createHash is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, angular5, node-modules

So I have this Angular 5 application which uses `aes256` library from NPM for encrypting password for login form. Inside that `aes256` library, theres `var crypto = require('crypto')`. When I run my application and try the login form, I encountered `crypto.createHash is not a function` error. 
When I debugged my app to find out whats wrong, I see that `var crypto` was just an empty object.
[crypto.createHash is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjPZD.png)
[crypto - empty object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I4F3.png)

Comment: im using nodejs 10.9.0

Comment: Have you tried using a different name instead of `crypto` for the variable? See [this](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Changes-related-to-node/_compare/de2b091ffc9a89a3c18ea86131a152e75e6dfae4...694fba92495d3b4f43bb62e86b3b6b47ae29fd53)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my react application. Have you figured out what is the real cause? @OpieOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use crypto module in angular application nor aes256 since it is build on crypto module. crypto module is a node native module you can't use any node native module from nodejs in angular application as it is running on the browser. Checkout some fronted encryption libraries [here](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441)

Answer (score 2):

You should use crypto-js library, this works for me

```
npm install crypto-js
npm install --save @types/crypto-js
```

Use it

```
import { SHA256, enc } from 'crypto-js';
```

```
const password = SHA256(this.loginForm.value.password).toString(enc.Hex);
```